# Checking Delimiter Using a Stack

Tags: java, stack, delimiter

The following code i have pasted below demonstrates how to check for a balance in delimiters(braces,brackets and parentheses) using a stack data structure.

```
import java.util.Stack;

class BracketChecker {
  private String input;

  public BracketChecker(String in) {
    input = in;
  }

  public void check() {
    Stack<Character> theStack = new Stack<Character>();

    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
      char ch = input.charAt(j);
      switch (ch) {
      case '{': 
      case '[':
      case '(':
        theStack.push(ch);
        break;
      case '}': 
      case ']':
      case ')':
        if (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
          char chx = theStack.pop();
          if ((ch == '}' && chx != '{') || (ch == ']' && chx != '[') || (ch == ')' && chx != '('))
            System.out.println("Error: " + ch + " at " + j);
        } else

          System.out.println("Error: " + ch + " at " + j);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!theStack.isEmpty()){
      System.out.println("Error: missing right delimiter");
    }
  }
}

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    input = "[]]()()";

    BracketChecker theChecker = new BracketChecker(input);
    theChecker.check();
  }

}
```

I had a bit of trouble in understanding the check method as i am new to java and was looking for a breakdown from someone. I will list below what i exactly understand so far (correct me if i am wrong). I would really appreciate it if someone can guide me there.

**What I Understand**

So first a stack is created of type char. Then a for loop is iterating through the input string char by char and if the variable ch is found it gets pushed in to the stack. However what i find weird is that from my understanding of a switch statement each case should have a action after it. In this case there is no action after case '{': or case '[': or case '('

Also if i am understanding this correct for the open delimiters the switch statement is suggesting a push action and for the closing ones its initiating a pop action, given that stack is not empty?

Can anyone please clear it up ? Also if possible show me a hand traced example with a small string .

Comment: "suggesting"? Statements don't get suggested, they get executed (I guess "initiated" is fine too and means the same thing).

Comment: If there is no break between case statements, then the evaluation "falls through". You can think of it as an or - If the character is { or [ or ( then push it to the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A switch statement executes all the case statements starting from the one that matches the condition and until it encounters break.

```
  case '{': 
  case '[':
  case '(':
    theStack.push(ch);
    break;
```

This code means that `theStack.push(ch)` is performed for any of '{','[' or '('.

As for an example, lets consider this String - `({}[])`

(The actual input String can contain non-brackets characters, but the algorithm ignores them, so we can ignore them too)

'(' pushed into the stack
'{' pushed into the stack
'}' pops '{' and find a match (if the stack is empty, or the popped bracket is of a different type, the check fails)
'[' pushed into the stack
']' pops '[' and finds a match
')' pops '(' and finds a match

After processing the String, the stack must be empty in order to pass the check (otherwise, there are un-closed brackets).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293668/inserting-node-in-a-sorted-linked-list

HI can you please check my new question.