# Inserting Node in a Sorted linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

[image]

The following code ensures that elements are inserted in a linked list in a sorted manner.

After understanding the logic behind this i decided to test it on my own. However when i wrote my version of the code it as follows.

```
  public class SortedList {

    private Node first;

    public SortedList() {
        first = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void insert(int j) {
        Node newNode = new Node(j);
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = first;

        while (current != null && j > current.iData) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (previous == null)
            first = newNode;

        else

            newNode.next = current;
        previous.next = newNode;

    }

    public Node remove() {
        Node temp = first;
        first = first.next;
        return temp;
    }

    public void displayList() {
        System.out.println("First to -----> Last");
        Node current = first;

        while (current != null) {
            current.display();
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

}
```

**NODE CLASS**

```
public class Node {

    public int iData;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int id) {
        iData = id;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(iData + " ");
    }

}
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
public class SortedListApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SortedList list = new SortedList();

        list.insert(20);
        list.insert(40);

        list.displayList();

        list.insert(10);
        list.insert(30);
        list.insert(50);

        list.displayList();

        list.remove();

        list.displayList();

    }

}
```

The only difference between the two is that in my version when the while loop terminates. I first set the next value of the newNode to the current and then i set the next value of previous to the new Node. In the original code posted they have it reversed. For some reason this throws Null Pointer Exception. I am wondering why?

From what i understand, once the new node finds its place for insertion. We have reference to the previous node and the current node and we are trying to insert the new node in the middle of the previous and the current. Therefore what i do is set the next of the new Node to the current and then i set the next of previous node to the new node.

Please tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace through this code when `previous` is null:

```
if (previous == null)
    first = newNode;
else
    newNode.next = current;
previous.next = newNode;
```

Notice that you never actually changed `previous` in the `if` statement, so this will try to write the `next` field of `null`, causing the crash.

If `previous` is null, then you need to prepend the node to the list, and in that case all you need to do is set `first` to `newNode` and make `newNode`'s next pointer point to the old list. In the case where `previous` isn't `null`, then you need to do two rewirings: you need to make `previous.next` point to the new node and for the new node's next pointer to point to the current node. You can fix this by writing

```
if (previous == null) {
    newNode.next = current;
    first = newNode;
}
else {
    newNode.next = current;
    previous.next = newNode;
}
```

Equivalently:

```
newNode.next = current;
if (previous == null)
    first = newNode;
else
    previous.next = newNode;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand your logic, i tried it. Although my program is not crashing it is not working perfectly as some values are not getting inserted properly. The only time its working perfectly well is when i first set the node of previous to next and then set the next of the new node to the current.

Comment: Does it work when you follow the example code you put in your question?

Comment: it works if i switch the order of newNode.next = current; and
    previous.next = newNode;

Comment: You are aware that the first statement is inside the `else` and the second executes unconditionally, right? Also, what's the default value of the `next` pointer for a node?

Comment: I copy pasted the code you suggested and replaced with mine and what happened was and it did not crash but acted weird. is it cool if i edit my question and paste my entire code so it might let u help me better? i am really stuck on this and i do not want to learn further till i understand whats wrong here

Comment: @user2733436 Whoops! I had a bug. Try the updated code - that looks better.

Comment: it works now, i still do not get what was wrong with my code originally. i am sorry is it possible for u to break down my mistake for me i know you explained but its going over my head.

Comment: @user2733436 When you interchanged the last two lines of the pseudocode, you moved the second-to-last line (which was part of the `else` branch) out of the else branch and exchanged it with something that happened unconditionally. In other words, you swapped code that was supposed to run all the time with code that was only supposed to run some of the time.